# Parse Error Unexpected element global-method-security' encountered"}

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, xml-parsing

I am using Spring MVC based project using xml configurations but while deploying the project I am getting below error:-

```
09:57:14,050 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."SpringMVC.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."SpringMVC.war".PARSE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "SpringMVC.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:189)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYUT0027: Failed to parse XML descriptor "/D:/Development_Folder/jboss-eap-7.4/bin/content/SpringMVC.war/WEB-INF/web.xml" at [109,2]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.WebParsingDeploymentProcessor.deploy(WebParsingDeploymentProcessor.java:136)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:182)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[109,2]
Message: Unexpected element '{http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://www.springframework.org/schema/security}global-method-security' encountered
    at org.jboss.metadata.parser.util.MetaDataElementParser.unexpectedElement(MetaDataElementParser.java:115)
    at org.jboss.metadata.parser.servlet.WebMetaDataParser.parse(WebMetaDataParser.java:196)
    at org.jboss.metadata.parser.servlet.WebMetaDataParser.parse(WebMetaDataParser.java:51)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.WebParsingDeploymentProcessor.deploy(WebParsingDeploymentProcessor.java:96)
    ... 9 more

09:57:14,052 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "SpringMVC.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"SpringMVC.war\".PARSE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment \"SpringMVC.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYUT0027: Failed to parse XML descriptor \"/D:/Development_Folder/jboss-eap-7.4/bin/content/SpringMVC.war/WEB-INF/web.xml\" at [109,2]
    Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[109,2]
Message: Unexpected element '{http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://www.springframework.org/schema/security}global-method-security' encountered"}}
09:57:14,054 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "SpringMVC.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"SpringMVC.war\".PARSE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment \"SpringMVC.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYUT0027: Failed to parse XML descriptor \"/D:/Development_Folder/jboss-eap-7.4/bin/content/SpringMVC.war/WEB-INF/web.xml\" at [109,2]
    Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[109,2]
```

The error line 109 is there in `web.xml`. The `web.xml` file is mentioned below:-

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>

        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm;</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>

    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>posturl</param-name>
        <param-value>https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- <context-param> <param-name>posturl</param-name> <param-value>https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr</param-value> 
        </context-param> -->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>SendGridKey</param-name>
        <param-value>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
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>cmd</param-name>
        <param-value>_xclick</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>business</param-name>
        <param-value>vidyareddy0591@gmail.com</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>password</param-name>
        <param-value>S6LEKZG9T9AJ7EHU</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>signature</param-name>
        <param-value>AiPC9BjkCyDFQXbSkoZcgqH3hpacAWLboo8SO7HpBsWSokvk8HXvlV1J
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>returnurl</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/paypal/success
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>cancelurl</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost:8080/paypal/cancel</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>ApplicationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            WEB-INF/security-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/SpringMVC/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <global-method-security
        pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
    <!-- <http pattern="/SpringMVC/" security="none"/> -->
    <http pattern="*/login/*" security="none" />
    <http pattern="*/signup/*" security="none" />

    <http pattern="*/SpringMVC/*"
        entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        create-session="stateless">
        <csrf disabled="true" />
        <custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"
            ref="jwtAuthenticationFilter" />
    </http>

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <http-basic />
    </http>
    <beans>
        <bean id="jwtAuthenticationFilter"
            class="com.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter">
            <property name="authenticationManager"
                ref="authenticationManager" />
            <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler"
                ref="jwtAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
        </bean>
    </beans>

    <authentication-manager
        alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider
            ref="jwtAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>

</web-app>
```

I have no previous idea about Spring MVC since I need to just deploy the same Spring MVC project into my machine to call the API from python code.

Please help in resolving this issue.

Comment: The tags from line 109 and 141 should not be part of web.xml, it should be part spring configuration xml. REF: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/helloworld-xml.html

Answer (score 1):

The following things are the spring-security stuff but you are now putting them in the `web.xml`. They are not defined by the servlet specification and hence the errors.

According to your configuration, they should be put in the `WEB-INF/security-context.xml`

```xml
     <global-method-security
        pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
    <!-- <http pattern="/SpringMVC/" security="none"/> -->
    <http pattern="*/login/*" security="none" />
    <http pattern="*/signup/*" security="none" />

    <http pattern="*/SpringMVC/*"
        entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        create-session="stateless">
        <csrf disabled="true" />
        <custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"
            ref="jwtAuthenticationFilter" />
    </http>

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <http-basic />
    </http>
    <beans>
        <bean id="jwtAuthenticationFilter"
            class="com.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter">
            <property name="authenticationManager"
                ref="authenticationManager" />
            <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler"
                ref="jwtAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
        </bean>
    </beans>

    <authentication-manager
        alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider
            ref="jwtAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. It means I need to put above lines in separate security-context.xml file. What would be the XML declaration and schema of this file. Can you please share the complete security-context.xml file with xml and xsd declaration.

Comment: Please be smart and search it out by yourself such as from the github likes [this](https://github.com/search?q=%22%3Cglobal-method-security%22&type=code)